# Glue job workaround: call lambda to get secrets. But that doesn't work from Glue (but does from EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-secrets-manager

I need to get a Python Shell Glue job some database credentials stored in AWS Secrets Manager.

This should be simple, but the organization I'm working for seems to have an obfuscatory Secrets Manager role that I so far haven't been able to modify to do what I want.

My workaround to call Lambda to get the secret to return to glue worked when I tested in on EC2, but from Glue the Lambda call hung forever. I made sure the role I was running on had 'Lambda Full Access', so that wasn't it.

Any ideas? Thanks much.

Comment: Duplicate question of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720927/trouble-updating-iam-to-allow-aws-glue-to-the-aws-secrets-manager/61722982?noredirect=1#comment109195977_61722982 ?

Answer (score 0):

My coworker switched from the AWS Glue Python Shell to Spark with Python and that worked!

Apparently there's something different about the network setup in the Python shell?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the previous incorrect answer: there was something about the code I was using in the Python Shell version that was causing the issue; I made some changes to the Spark Python version and got it to work.

One performance note: Spark takes 11-14 minutes just to *start* running the Python, where the Python shell starts pretty much immediately. So the latter is much faster to debug.